# How to display the next text lines once user presses the next button?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, io, jtextarea

I am trying to create a program which allows the user to choose a text file
from their directory. That then gets displayed in a `JTextArea` within the Frame created using Swing.

I've created a button with a action command that's supposed to allow the user once pressed to get the next text lines from the file, displayed within the text area until it reaches the end of file.

To do that I used the sub-string command to go through the String variable and display it .
But it seems to not to do that instead it just displays all the text found within the file.

Below you will find the code that allows the program to open the file and display as well 
as the buttons created to aid in navigating through the text.

```
package reader;

public class Viewer extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static JFrame Frame;
    private JPanel Cpanel;

    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    String book = "";
    int currentChar = 10;
    static JTextArea textArea;
    JFileChooser fileChooser;
    File f;

    public static void DocViewer() {

        new Viewer("new document");
    }

    public Viewer(String s) {
        Frame = new JFrame("Reader");

        textArea = new JTextArea(20,60);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        f = new File("C://Program Files//Java//jdk1.6.0//bin//");
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser(f);
        Frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);

        Frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));


        Cpanel = new JPanel();
        Cpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        Cpanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        JButton StButton = new JButton("open");
        JButton QButton = new JButton("back");
        JButton TestButton = new JButton("next");
        TestButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);

        StButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String book = "";
                // int currentChar=10;

                int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(Viewer.this);
                try {

                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

                    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
                    BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(fin, "UTF-8"));

                    book = "";
                    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                         while (book != null) { 
                             book = d.readLine();
                            textArea.append(book + "\n"); 
                        System.out.println(book);
                         }
                    }

                    System.out.println("returnVal = " + returnVal
                            + " and ba.fileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION = "
                            + JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION);
                    fin.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }

            }

        });

        QButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // System.exit(0);
                Viewer.EXIT_ON_CLOSE();
                Loader.main(null);

            }
        });

        TestButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String page = "";

                for (int l = 1; l >= 10; l = l + 2) {
                    page += book.substring(l, l + 49);

                    page += "\n";
                    currentChar += 50;

                }

            }
        });

        Cpanel.add(StButton);
        Cpanel.add(QButton);
        Cpanel.add(TestButton);





        Frame.add(Cpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Frame.setSize(300,300);
        Frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Rather than ..what you are attempting, why not simply put the text area in a scroll pane and load the entire file.  Instead of 'clicking a button' for the next lines of text, the user can 'click a scroll bar' (or press the page down/up button, or the home or end button or use the arrow keys..).

Comment: Well, you're ignoring `currentChar`, so the next time you press `TestButton`, you'll get the same result...Better to use `StringBuilder` then `String` cataternation in a loop...You're also not doing anything with the result (in `TestButton`)...Also, you seem to be loading the entire contents of the file into the text area...Would be better to load the file into some kind of `List` and simply iterate over the list...

Comment: thank you is any exercises out there that i can look at in terms the use of Stringbuilder and list.

Comment: The thing i want the users to click the button which clears whatevers in the Jtextarea and display the next couple of lines and due to having the file within the String Variable called book wouldnt that allow the substring to go through the characters or am i getting it wrong.

Comment: If you keep the lines of the file in a list it is fairly easy to show those lines in sequence (one after the other).  But again I question why not simply load the ***entire*** file to the text area, and either have the user use scroll bars etc.  ***or*** have the `next` and `back` buttons just reposition the text area in the scroll pane?  Or in other words, **why such a strange and unusual user interface?**  Is this homework designed to teach use of list structures?  If not, I would change the requirement.

Comment: i wish it was like that but my teacher wants me to create something similar to the amazon kindles interface is there anyway i can achieve that using the code that i have got already sir

Comment: Throw that code out and start over. Well at least throw out all your ActionListener code.

Comment: ok but without these code then i will have no way to do this

Comment: Not. If. You. Write. New. Better. Code. -- which is what we're trying to get you to do.

Comment: So, is the **requirement** to load a file in parts?  If not, I think that is irrelevant.  If you want to make a 'Kindle Like' interface, it can be achieved by hiding the scroll bars and using buttons to advance the (completely loaded) text in the scroll pane.

Comment: say if i create a new actionlistener code which doesnt have filechooser but instead has a pathfile such as (C:mydoc\test.txt) of the file that i wish to display then create actionlistner for the button to display the next line would i be able to use a scanner to scan the file from either a certain charachter or line

Comment: yes sir the requirement is to load a file in parts also sir could you elaborate on the part you said about hiding the scroll bar and using the button

Comment: Please post your actual requirements verbatim as that requirement sounds ludicrous. I have to wonder if you might be misinterpreting them.

Comment: maybe i am misinterpreting them but my requirements are to load a text file and display it in to the textarea where the user can see the the text and then have the ability to press a button which displays the next portion of the text on to the frame as well pressing another button to go back to previous portion of the text. i hope this clears it up

Comment: Yes, you're misinterpreting it. There is no requirement that the file needs to be re-read. Again, we would recommend that you read the whole thing in at once, and into an ArrayList as several have suggested. The only exception is if it is so large that you run out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your code is only doing what you tell it to do.
2. Your button's ActionListener has a while loop that loops through the entire file writing all the contents to the JTextArea. So I'm not sure why this behavior surprises you.
3. If it were me, I'd read the entire file into an `ArrayList<String>` with each new line being added one at a time. I'd do this once, perhaps in a class constructor if you know what file to read in advance, perhaps in response to getting a File via a JFileChooser if you don't.
4. Then in my button grab the next line in this List, using an int index variable to store the index number, and append this line to my JTextArea.
5. Maybe even better than using a JTextArea would be to use a JList.

Done.

---

**Edit**
You've asked more questions, so I'll try to subdivide the steps a little:

- Create an `ArrayList<String>` as an instance field (non-static class variable)
- Open your file put it into a Scanner object
- Using a while loop, loop while the Scanner has a next line
- Inside the loop, use the Scanner to grab the next line and put it into the List.
- Also give the class an int index field.
- On button push, get the String in the ArrayList corresponding to the index, and then increment the index
- Publish that String in your JTextField using its append method.

If still stuck, break down **your** steps even further and try to find specifically where you're stuck. Google for a solution, and if still stuck, come here with your specific question and code.

Check the [java](/questions/tagged/java) [info resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info). In particular look at the Beginner's resources for links.

---

As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter.

Comment: I am sorry to ask question but how do i do this could you point me to right direction is there any exercises or examples that look at.

Comment: @user1836382: I've outlined the basics, surely you've found the Java tutorials. If still stuck, please ask more specific question if possible. Very broad questions are hard to answer other than with a "the tutorials are here", and again, I'm sure you've already found them. So again -- where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: i am sorry i am new to this dont know where to find the tutorial